# Windows 7 snap - Programmatic aspect

Tags: windows, windows-7, winapi

Windows 7 has a new "snap" feature it applies when dragging "standard" windows. I do have a pure win32 application (not MFC or any other framework) that I use to create a non-orthodox user-drawn window.

That window does not "conform" to windows 7 snap and dragging it to screen corners will not do anything.

Do I need a special style/class or something similar in my window in order for windows 7 to take it into consideration for "snapping"

Comment: You know that what matters is that your mouse cursor reaches the edge of the screen, not that your app reaches the corner, yes?

Comment: Yes Kate...... the same grabbing and dragging that causes the automatic "snap" with other windows, more standard ones, doesn't work with my custom user drawn window. I figured it might either be messages I'm not responding to, or maybe window style.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [WindowChrome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.shell.windowchrome.aspx) class which is in the Microsoft.Windows.Shell namespace available in .NET 4. If you are targeting .NET 3.5 SP1 there is a backported standalone library, [details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2010/02/22/wpf-shell-integration-library-for-net-3-5.aspx).